# Array of static objects - keeps the last value across the whole array?

Tags: java, arrays, static

I am really stumped with my code:

I have a static class:

```
static class Test
{
           static b;
           static c;
}
```

and in my main class, I have initialized an array of static Test.

```
Test[] AB = new Test[5];
```

I then fill the array with:

```
for(int a=0; a<AB.length; a++)
{
int C = new int();
int D = new int();
C = get user input here....
D = get user input here...
AB[a].c = C;
AB[a].b = D;
}
```

When I output the array, all my values are the last values inputted. Basically, if user last inputted C = 5, D = 4. All the values from AB[0] - AB[4] for c and b are 5 and 4.

I'm really stumped.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Static variables have the same value across all instances of a class.

Comment: @Codebender Seems like pseudo logic to me. Not actual code.

Comment: @Suresh, Ya.. that's right...

Comment: how are you accessing static classes.  you can't declare top level static classes

Comment: So many errors in that code, e.g. `new Test[5]` does *not* allocate 5 objects of type `Test`. It only allocates an *array* of 5 *references*, that are all `null`. --- `new int()` is meaningless in Java. --- `static b` has no type.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Andreas Ironically, being static members makes `AB[a].c = ..` (where `AB[a]` evaluates to null, and the expression is of type Test) compile fine .. and not throw a NPE when executed. The other problems remain, however.

Comment: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Comment: @user2864740 Wow, you are so right. Dang! So *this* is what code obfuscation looks like. Of course, I never actually *said* it would throw NPE. (Saved by the bell)

Comment: Ok, ok, here is a constructive comment: Please post questions that are *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable*. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

static values are shared across all the instance. You need to take instance members. Not static.

Create a normal class and take instance members, then you can have instance specific values of them.